# Running tcl file from terminal

Tags: path, terminal, tcl, execute

I am new to TCL scripting and trying to run the script from terminal.

If i run the script like

```
tclsh myscript.tcl
```

then the script is executing without any issue.

But, if I run directly without "tclsh", then it is throwing error as follows,

```
./myscript.tcl
./myscript: Command not found.
```

I have given the execution permission for that file.

I have added the tclsh path in the PATH variable

```
echo  $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/tclsh
```

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Does your script htave the required shebang line? e.g. `#!/usr/local/bin/tclsh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with adding:

`#!/usr/bin/tclsh`

In the beginning of your script.

If still doesn't work please show us your script you're trying to run, maybe there's something wrong.

Comment: Clearly not the case here, but it's common to see `#!/usr/bin/env tclsh` if the location of tcl is "non-standard" but it is in the PATH.

Comment: The biggest issue with using the system Tclsh as someone who isn't an OS distributor is that you're never 100% sure what version it is.

Comment: @DonalFellows Doesn't `package require Tcl <version>` in the script solve that?

Comment: @potrzebie It does not "solve it", but at least it will let your script fail gracefuly.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I expect that the system administrator has linked `tclsh` to the latest version. That's really his job, not my script's.

Comment: Usually the packages will do that, I don't know much about perl (I have it on my linux box) so I don't care what version I have. Once someone complains that he needs a newer version, I can do some things, but until this happens, I'll let my packet manager do that job.